# How to make sessions unique for each user? - Node.js

Tags: node.js, session, unique, sessionid

I am working on a node project at the moment and my problem is that if I log into the website on one computer and I do the same for the other computer I will still be logged in into the account. I think this has to do with a problem with making the sessions unique.Here is the middleware that I am using for the session:

```
app.use(session({
    secret:"HelloWorld"
}));
```

If anyone wants to see the node file here it is: http://pastebin.com/euatwkNS

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `genid` method.

```
app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) { return uuid(); },
    secret:"HelloWorld"
}));
```

You already have `uuid` imported. It should work.

> NOTE be careful to generate unique IDs so your sessions do not conflict.

More info in: [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Comment: Doesn't work, I uploaded the site to dynamiccomps.herokuapp.com and the user is still signed in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have't specified where express-session should store session data. From within the [express-session docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session): "Warning The default server-side session storage, `MemoryStore`, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing."

I am not sure why they are not giving examples of correctly specifying it within their docs, but the correct way to do this should be something like what I got:

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const app = express();
... // configure mongoose db and connect

const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);

const month = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; // ms * s * min * h * days
var sess = {
    secret: 'session-secret',
    resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
    cookie: { maxAge: month }, // do not allows js on client to touch cookies
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
};
app.use(session(sess));
```

Note the line `store: new MongoStore(...)`, that is how store is specified. I used [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) package for store, which depends on mongoose, but I see you are using monk, which I don't see listed as existing stores, thus you might have to create your own store or move to using mongoose. A full list of existing stores is given at the end of [express-session docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).