# Is it safe to use UUID v4 to generate session IDs?

Tags: node.js, http, session-cookies, uuid

Is it safe to use UUID v4 to generate session IDs?

Does generating two UUID v4 and concatenating them to have a longer string make this more secure to be used as a session ID for a web app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make sessions unique for each user? - Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143911/how-to-make-sessions-unique-for-each-user-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no. While the string itself is long enough, the UUID specification does not require implementations to generate strings that are cryptographically random.

Specific implementations *may* make it more random, so the library you use might be good enough, but it's not required to be a valid UUID. So having a valid UUID is no proof/guarantee that it was generated from a random enough source.

Even if your specific UUID library does create cryptograhically unguessable strings, it may still not be desirable to use it, because it could signal to a future developer: "UUIDs are safe to use for secrets", so it could create risk later on even if originally the UUIDs were secure.

My recommendation would be to simply use `crypto.randomBytes`

Comment: Will there be any difference if I convert those random bytes to hex vs base64? to hex would look nicer then to base64 and I guess one or the other it's just a display "style" and data behind it is just as random and unique in both cases.

Comment: @daniels you need to convert it to *something*. Hex is longer